# Generics in Java, universal function

Tags: java, generics

I've got two classes, both of them contains ObservableList but filled with different objects. In other logic class I have the function which returns me appropriate object of the list:

```
public CarTableView findCarTableView( Button button) {
    for(CarTableView carnet : carTableViewModel.getObservableList()) {
        if(carnet.getActionButton().equals(button)) {
            return carnet;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

1st Class:

```
public class CustomerTableView extends Customer{

    private ObservableList<CustomerTableView> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); //HERE
    private Button actionButton;

    public CustomerTableView(String name, String surname, String city, 
                             String postCode, String street,
                             String localNumber, Button actionButton) {
        super(name, surname, city, postCode, street, localNumber);
        this.actionButton=actionButton;
    }
}
```

2nd Class:

```
public class CarTableView  extends Car{

    private ObservableList<CarTableView> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); //HERE
    private  Button actionButton;

    public CarTableView(String brand, String engine, String yearOfProduction, 
                        boolean navi, boolean available, int power, 
                        Button actionButton) {
        super(brand, engine, yearOfProduction, navi, available, power);
        this.actionButton=actionButton;
    }
}
```

But this function works only for one object from specific class. I found out the Generics functonality, but i came across one problem. In this function I have to use specific methods with both of these classes have (`getActionButton()` ,`getObservableList()`)

I came across such code, but compiler inform me about lack of these functions, how can I do it better?

```
public <T> T findCarTableView(T t, Button button) {
    for(T carnet : t.getObservableList()) {
        if(carnet.getActionButton().equals(button)) {
            return carnet;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Updated but still dont fix my problem

Comment: "compiler inform me about lack of these functions" - what do you mean? Do you get a compile error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: The method getObservableList() is undefined for the type T

Comment: Don't run before you can walk. Just copy and paste the function. It's not a big deal in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the compiler doesn't know any boundary for `T` and thus has to assume `Object`. Hence `t.getObservableList()` can't work because that method isn't present in `Object`.

To make this work provide a common interface or super class and use that as a boundary for `T`:

```
interface CommonInterface<T extends CommonInterface<T>> {
  Collection<T> getObservableList();
}

public <T extends CommonInterface<T>> T findCarTableView(T t, Button button) {
  for(T carnet : t.getObservableList()) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the objects of type `T` contain other observables of the same type. If that's not the case then change your interface and the method to something like this:

```
interface CommonInterface<T> {
  Collection<T> getObservableList();
}

public <T> T findCarTableView(CommonInterface<T> t, Button button) {
  for(T carnet : t.getObservableList()) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Thanks, I'm accepting answer

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface that has getActionButton() and getObservableList() methods. CarTableView and CustomerTableView must implement it.

```
public TableView findCarTableView(TableView t, Button button) {
    for(T carnet : t.getObservableList()) {
        if(carnet.getActionButton().equals(button)) {
            return carnet;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

where TableView is your interface.

Comment: I thought about this, but the `ObservableList`s contain different types too.

Comment: And use ObservableList<TableView>